# How do I compile the Kyber m4 implementation in Linux?

Tags: compilation, cryptography, arm, cross-compiling, m4

I am trying to compile the C code of CRYSTALS-Kyber given on the [website](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/), more precisely the m4 implementation. But there's no makefile and I have no idea how to compile it otherwise...

I tried to make a Makefile, with the following lines

`all: kyber

kyber :
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -static main.c kem.c aes256ctr.c cbd.c randombytes.c aes.c fastaddsub.S fastbasemul.S fastinvntt.S fastntt.S indcpa.c ntt.c poly.c polyvec.c reduce.S verify.c -o ./kem`

Plus, I had to download files "aes.c" and "randombytes.c" because there were included in others files but were not in the folder. I don't even know if I downloaded the right ones. (I took them from [this github](https://github.com/mupq/pqm4). When I try to build the project, I have errors such as "undefined reference towards aes128_*encrypt*_fss" or "conflicting architecture profiles M/A"

Comment: There is no ARM m4 implementation on the CRYSTALS-Kyber website; the PQM4 project does ship one though. What are you specifically trying to compile though, because the source files that you list are the Kyber library, do not define `main()` and thus can't be compiled without `-c`.